# numpy matrix multiplication each col and sum

Tags: python, numpy

I have some matrices:

```
A = np.array([[0.8, 0.2],
              [0.4, 0.6]])
B = np.array([0.4, 0.2])
C = np.array([0.28, 0.06])
```

And what I want to do is:

```
S = A.shape[0]
what_I_need = np.zeros([S])
for s in range(S):
    what_I_need[s] = np.sum(A[:, s] * C) * B[s]
print(what_I_need)
```

The result is

```
[0.0992 0.0184]
```

Is there an elegant or pythonic way to do this without for loop? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `matrix-multiplication` -

```
A.T.dot(C)*B # or C.dot(A)*B
```

With a single call to `np.einsum` -

```
np.einsum('ij,i,j->j',A,C,B) #use `optimize` flag for better perf.
```